# Open Source software for Quadcopters

Tags: quadcopter

my question is general so please bear with me. I'm now interested in buying a quadcopter and develop some functions that it does for example an android app to control it, or objects detection. 
So my question is what are the available quadcopters which has a software that allows me to do such things not just a flying toy?

P.S: I'm asked to buy a kit within 600$ and not build it by myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. ROS is not the Jack of all trades when there is a question related to robotics. It is just a frame to help you handle package communication between different nodes(functions).
2. You can buy a kit of 3D-robotics' quadcopter. Their APM flight controller is an open-sourced control system based on Arduino and you can modify its framework and download it into the quadcopter. All source are available in their [github](https://github.com/diydrones/ardupilot).
3. If you don't want to pay too much attention on low-level development, which means the control control algorithm itself, and you want to develop some applications based on the quadcopter. It is another good choice to try AR.Drone, which provides many APIs.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm considering the third choice that you mentioned, developing applications based on the quadcopter, After a search online this drone caught my eyes
[link](http://www.parrot.com/uk/products/bebop-drone/)
but i'm wondering can i access its system (linux as they said) like accessing other devices such as Raspberry Pi in order to manipulate certain things?

Comment: @DieDen No, you cannot. The link you mentioned only says it provides APIs instead of full access of the system. check it [here](https://github.com/ARDroneSDK3/ARSDKBuildUtils) But I think this is enough to build the high-level application development. You do need to have all access like Raspberry Pi because all inside is inside here, you just need to get/set parameters' value for your purpose.

Comment: thanks a lot I really appreciate your help and quick response :)

Answer (score 0):

On the controller side, the following is a great starting point: http://ros.org/.

For drone itself, checkout http://diydrones.com/group/rosusergroup as they will know how to best integrate the controller with an off-the-shelf drone.

Cheers,